# Magento Main menu - custom link not showing up

Tags: magento

This a custom Magento single main navigation link I have it was showing up before I changed About Us to another word and then back to About Us now wont show up. Any ideas? thanks

`<ul>
<li class="level0 level-top right"><a href="http://www.hi/index.php/about-magento-demo-store/"><span class="level-top"><span>About Us</span></span></a></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to know from your brief description. Are you telling us that when you click on the link it is broken?

It looks like you have a typing error in the href URL for the top level domain `/www.hi/`

Or are you saying that on the page you don't see the hyperlink at all? There is nothing wrong with your HTML so if you can't see the link I suggest you inspect the CSS or try to work out if any JavaScript is hiding the element.

If it is neither of these things please re-write your question with meticulous detail.

Comment: I just made the url generic and yeah you can't see "About Us". I know there is the option to refresh javascript/css in Magento. Would that be my problem? I wanna hit that button and hope it doesn't wreck any code.

Comment: I inpected in firefox looks like this. Also did Magento css/java refresh no change.<ul>
<li class="level0 level-top right"><a href="http://111.111.11.11/index.php/about-magento-demo-store/"><span class="level-top"><span>About Us</span></span></a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Please edit your question and use the `code` formatting. I can't read your HTML in the above comment. Are your certain it is not malformed HTML or Malformed CSS. I mean, really it has to be because we can see your 'About Us' text is in the source code. Pay close attention to the CSS classes - it is a menu so maybe one fo those cclasses is hiding the text 'About Us' or is shifting the words off the page.

Comment: SOLVED! So when you edit in Magento it automatically adds <ul> at the beginning and end so you have to delete, save, then flush cache. :)